# Is there any way to implement drill down in flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, syncfusion, drilldown

- I have implemented drill down option in javascript.
- Is there any option I can use it as it is in flutter ?
- I am using flutter to develop a android and ios application.
- Or is there any way I can implement a drill down in flutter application.
- For those who don't know what drill down is. The below image[image] would help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved using the onPointTapped event. In this event, you can get the point index on which you have tapped. With this information, you can render the chart based on your requirement. After drill down, we have provided an icon with a back arrow, can be used to get back to the actual chart. Find the code below to accomplish this.

```
SfCircularChart(
 onPointTapped: (PointTapArgs args) {
      getDrilledChart(args.pointIndex);
 }
//Other configurations,
)
```

The sample for reference can be found below.

[Drill down sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/drilldown-1055299914)

Screenshot before drill down

[image: Before]

Screenshot after drill down

[image: After]